# String to array then remove last element

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have the strings below and I am trying to remove the last directory from them but I cant seem to get the grasp of it.

JavaScript

```
var x = path.split("/")
alert(path +' = ' +x.slice(0, -1));
```

Expected Result

```
/foo/bar/ = /foo/
/bar/foo/ = /bar/
/bar/foo/moo/ = /bar/foo/
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try:

```js
let path = "/bar/foo/moo/";
let split = path.split("/");
let splicedStr = split.slice(0, split.length - 2).join("/") + "/";
console.log(splicedStr);
```

Comment: Thanks very much, just need to change var split to x

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
var sourcePath="/abc/def/ghi";
var lastIndex=sourcePath.lastIndexOf("/");
var requiredPath=sourcePath.slice(0,lastIndex+1);
```

Output:   /abc/def/