# Obtaining the path of a string with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a simple mouseover in joomla, so i'm using javascript
a1 and a2 are just a sample of the type of paths i will be dealing with

the path i get has the word underfined in it, i tried to replace that with an empty string

but it isn't working

my question is how do i get rid of underdefined or is there a better way? can i split at the last instance of '/'?

```
    var a1 = '/joomla/images/vipportfolio/P5_over.jpg';
    var a2 = '/joomla/images/vipportfolio/P5.jpg';

    var pathArray = a1.split( '/' ); //pathArray.length
    //alert(a1.pathname)
    var path;
    for(var i = 0;i < pathArray.length - 1 ;i++)
    {
        if(pathArray[i]===undefined){ pathArray[i] = '' }
        path += pathArray[i] + '/';
    }
    alert(path) //returns under fined//joomla/images/vipportfolio/
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [String to array then remove last element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130394/string-to-array-then-remove-last-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't need a for loop, you could use `substring()` and `lastIndexOf()` functions.

```
var path = a1.substring(0, a1.lastIndexOf('/') +1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var path = a1;
    var split = path.split("/");
    var x = split.slice(0, split.length - 1).join("/") + "/";
    alert(x);*
```